# Setting cross domain cookie with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, cookies

Let's say I have domain a.com and b.com, and I own both domains. There's a page on b.com called setcookie.aspx and in the server code, it sets a cookie under the b.com domain.

I want to make an HTTP get request to b.com/setcookie.aspx from a.com (b.com is already allowing CORS requests from a.com) like so:

$.get('http://www.b.com/setcookie.aspx');

For some reason, the cookie is not being set. However, if I put the URL in a hidden image tag:

<img src="http://www.b.com/setcookie.aspx" style="display: none;" />

Then it works. Any idea why the AJAX request doesn't set the cookie?

Comment: `$.get` uses `XMLHttpRequest` - read the documentation regarding cookies [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) - `XmlHttpRequest responses from a different domain cannot set cookie values for their own domain unless withCredentials is set to true before making the request, regardless of Access-Control- header values` - so, you need to set the jQuery equivalent of `withCredentials` - note, you'll need jQuery 1.5.1+ for this to work - and you probably wont be able to use `$.get` - use `$.ajax` instead

Comment: @JaromandaX actually newer versions allow passing a settings object to the shorthand methods like `$.get` and `$.post` ... but agree is just as easy to use `$.ajax`

Comment: @charlietfl - I must've missed that in the documentation!

Comment: Setting withCredentials to true worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make 2 changes.

### On a.com

As pointed out by @Jaromanda X in the comments, you need to set `withCredentials=true` in your `$.get` request. Cross-domain cookies are not allowed to be set by browsers unless you do this. Read this [XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)

### On b.com

When a cookie is to be set from the server side, it will send a header of the form:

> set-cookie: key=val; expires=Fri, 24-Jan-20 10:29:58 GMT; path=/; domain=example.com; HttpOnly; **SameSite=Lax**

Notice the `SameSite=Lax` flag. **This prevents the browser from setting cookie across domains.**

> From the [Mozilla Set-Cookie docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)
>
> Asserts that a cookie must not be sent with cross-origin requests,
> providing some protection against cross-site request forgery attacks

You need to disable this flag. This will depend on your backend platform. I use Django and for me it was just changing 1 setting [SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE). **This allows me to set the session id cookie to be set via a cross-domain AJAX request.**

Once you do these 2 changes, the cross-domain cookie will be set. **However, make sure to have enough CORS and CSRF checks to ensure the request comes from trusted origins**.